# ACF — поле которое можно добавлять много(бесконечное число) раз?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Подскажите по Custom Fields. Допустим есть поле для добавления. Например, поле услуга на странице услуг(как на скрине, поле в виде идентичных блоков с разными текстом и картинкой просто) И таких полей однообразных нужно много.

Есть логичный вариант, сделать таких полей например штук 40 под запас готовых.

Но можно ли сделать просто одно поле такое и добавлять его на странице бесконечное число раз(наполняя разным текстом)? Чтобы не делать однотипные поля в огромном размере.

[image: пример - поле=блок]

Comment: Без плагина точно можно. Просто добавлять-удалять поля джаваскриптом по клику на кнопке или по заполняемости предыдущих полей.

Comment: не смог понять что имеете в виду. Есть статья/урок на эту тему посмотреть?

Comment: ACF Repeater, можешь не благодарить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответили - ACF repeater. Спасибо.